# Conditionally update value of a custom attribute in password reset user journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to update value of one of the extension attribute(extension_StatusFlag) in password reset user journey. I only want to do it if and only if extension_StatusFlag attribute has value of MigratedNotActivated. There could be 4 possible different values of extension_StatusFlag.

I have added a OrchestrationStep with Preconditions to check the value of extension_StatusFlag and if condition satisfies then only call a technical profile to update the property value.

Have added below OrchestrationStep step in PasswordReset user journey

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_StatusFlag</Value>
          <Value>MigratedNotActivated</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Update_extension_StatusFlagToActive" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountChange_extension_StatusFlagToActiveUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

I created a technical profile like below  :

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountChange_extension_StatusFlagToActiveUsingObjectId">
      <DisplayName>Change extension_StatusFlag to active</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      </InputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteAccountStatusUsingObjectId" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Then a Validation technical profile :

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteAccountStatusUsingObjectId">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_StatusFlag" DefaultValue="Active" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

My problem is even though extension_StatusFlag has value of MigratedNotActivated still this OrchestrationStep is not executing. Value of extension_StatusFlag remains same. Looks like it is not able to update the attribute value. 
Note  : I have made sure that extension_StatusFlag attribute is in claim bag because I can see that in returned claims when user is done with password reset and cookie is issued.

I expect it to save the attribute value to Active but it is not doing it. Looks like it is skipping it all together and not at all calling the technical profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concluding the answer which was suggested by @chrispadgett and worked so aboslutly fine. If someone need to refer it would be easy. 
you can just use below Orchestration Step

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_StatusFlag</Value>
          <Value>MigratedNotActivated</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Update_extension_StatusFlagToActive" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteAccountStatusUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

And inside the step you can just call Write technical profile

```
  <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteAccountStatusUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_StatusFlag" DefaultValue="Active" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Note : This is only applicable if you dont want to collect any information from user by presenting a screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the **AlwaysUseDefaultValue** attribute to the **PersistedClaim** element:

```xml
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_StatusFlag" DefaultValue="Active" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

Otherwise, if the **extension_StatusFlag** claim has an existing value (i.e. `MigratedNotActivated`), then it isn't replaced with the new value.

Comment: Hi Chris - Thanks for response. I made the change and tried and it did not work. Looks like AAD-UserWriteAccountStatusUsingObjectId is not getting called. As per the MS documentation If there is no any output claim to present to the user, Azure AD B2C skips the technical profile. Here is the reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile. I added executed-SelfAsserted-Input claim as true with lot many combinations and it did not help.

Comment: Hi @RupeshKumarprasad. What happens if you refer directly from the orchestration step to the **AAD-UserWriteAccountStatusUsingObjectId** technical profile rather than indirectly through the **LocalAccountChange_extension_StatusFlagToActiveUsingObjectId** technical profile?

Comment: Hi Chris - This worked. I am not sure why this did not work in the first time when i tried before because i remember i directly called Write technical profile from orchestration step and it did not work, probably i was missing AlwaysUseDefaultValue attribute.

Comment: Yes, you must include the **AlwaysUseDefaultValue** attribute. Also, I believe a self-asserted technical profile doesn't execute if it doesn't include any output claims. I'll add this to the above answer...